# How to add Links to a Bootstrap Navigation Bar in Django?

Tags: django

I have tried to Add Links to a Bootstrap Navigation Bar for login page of Django that finally save in Django administration
here is my base.html file

```
<html>
     <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        {%block head %}
        <title>Base</title>
        {% endblock %} 
    </head>

    <body>
    
        <br>
        <div class="container">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
              aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Social Network</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            {%if user.is_authenticated %}
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li><a href="/account">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/account/login">login</a></li>
                <li><a href="/account/profile">profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/account/profile/edit">edit profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/account/logout">logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            {% else %}
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="/account/login">login</a></li>
              <li><a href="/account/register">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

        {% block body%}
            <h1>Base</h1>
        {% endblock %} 
    </body>
</html>
```

before it worked not very sort but it worked. I checked another question but I couldn't find my solution

Answer (score 0):

use `url` and pass your defined `url` name. for example if name of login `url` is login:

```
<li><a href="{% url "login" %}">login</a></li>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [

    path('login/', your_views, name="login"),
]
```

Comment: when i added this (NameError: name 'path' is not defined)

Comment: you need to import `path` and your `view`. I have edited the answer

Comment: still it doesn't work :)

Comment: Update your post with views.py, urls.py snippet